# Sublime plugins can't find nodejs

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3

I installed Sublime text, and I was trying to setup it for javascript development. But either this plugin or sublime itself can't find path to 'node'.
Here is the error message:

[image]

Here is the path where node and nodejs are installed:

[image]

Here is the plugin settings, I've tried both paths, "/usr/local/bin/node", "/usr/bin/nodejs". But still, there is error message:

[image]

And it happens also with eslint and htmlprettify plugins. They just throw an error, that they couldn't find the node path.

Comment: I have the same issue, and have made the following post on the Sublime HQ Forums: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/bug-sublime-text-cant-find-nodejs-on-pop-os/55553